# Obtain column A of df1 based on matches between column B in df1 and column C in df2

Tags: r

If `dmrcate.granges.hyper$overlapping.genes` is in `gst.region.bp.hyper$SigGenesInSet`, add the `gst.region.bp.hyper$TERM` column to a new column `dmrcate.granges.hyper$Pathway`.

If `dmrcate.granges.hyper$overlapping.genes` is in multiple rows of `gst.region.bp.hyper$SigGenesInSet`, take the `gst.region.bp.hyper$TERM` from the row with the lowest value in `gst.region.bp.hyper$P.DE`.

Delete rows with no corresponding `TERM`.

Attempt:

```
pathway <- gst.region.subset.hyper$TERM[dmrcate.granges.hyper$overlapping.genes %in% gst.region.bp.hyper$SigGenesInSet]
```

Input:

```
> dmrcate.granges.hyper
GRanges object with 1133 ranges and 8 metadata columns:
         seqnames            ranges strand |   no.cpgs min_smoothed_fdr  Stouffer
            <Rle>         <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>        <numeric> <numeric>
     [1]     chr6 31595647-31603535      * |        44                0         0
     [2]     chr6 31852301-31859141      * |        42                0         0
     [3]     chr6 33231268-33237583      * |        33                0         0
     [4]     chr6 30156394-30160639      * |        24                0         0
     [5]     chr6 30165961-30167363      * |        22                0         0
     ...      ...               ...    ... .       ...              ...       ...
  [1129]    chr22 39529123-39529217      * |         4                0         0
  [1130]    chr22 41572924-41573176      * |         4                0         0
  [1131]    chr22 41741892-41742086      * |         4                0         0
  [1132]    chr22 46508486-46509534      * |         4                0         0
  [1133]    chr22 46859616-46860524      * |         4                0         0
                HMFDR    Fisher   maxdiff  meandiff      overlapping.genes
            <numeric> <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>            <character>
     [1] 3.44625e-227         0         0         0                 PRRC2A
     [2] 1.79989e-227         0         0         0                  EHMT2
     [3] 2.99916e-228         0         0         0                  VPS52
     [4] 7.57642e-218         0         0         0                 TRIM26
     [5] 2.36880e-217         0         0         0                 TRIM26
     ...          ...       ...       ...       ...                    ...
  [1129] 9.84002e-204         0         0         0                   CBX7
  [1130] 5.92077e-215         0         0         0 EP300, RP1-85F18.6, ..
  [1131] 4.40477e-213         0         0         0                 ZC3H7B
  [1132] 3.33913e-200         0         0         0 FLJ27365, MIRLET7A3,..
  [1133] 5.19253e-196         0         0         0                 CELSR1
  -------
  seqinfo: 22 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths

> dput(gst.region.bp.hyper[1:10,])
structure(list(ONTOLOGY = c("BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", 
"BP", "BP", "BP", "BP"), TERM = c("post-transcriptional gene silencing by RNA", 
"post-transcriptional gene silencing", "miRNA-mediated gene silencing", 
"gene silencing by RNA", "chromosome condensation", "post-transcriptional regulation of gene expression", 
"response to temperature stimulus", "cellular response to heat", 
"miRNA-mediated gene silencing by inhibition of translation", 
"response to heat"), N = c(131, 134, 127, 162, 27, 332, 66, 26, 
26, 45), DE = c(18, 18, 17, 22, 9, 45, 13, 9, 6, 10), P.DE = c(0.000818260245628621, 
0.000873836947214564, 0.00112669446509654, 0.00202094618919135, 
0.0053206198528511, 0.00571117022340636, 0.00587675453613704, 
0.00907318653060527, 0.0130919680534733, 0.0132450219599635), 
    FDR = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SigGenesInSet = c("PRRC2A,MIR922,MIR939,MIR1249,MIR1237,EIF4G1,AGO2,DND1,MIRLET7A3,MIRLET7B,MIR182,MIR183,MIR33A,MIR96,MIR339,MAP2K2,MIR769,NCOR2,MARF1", 
    "MIR877,MIR922,MIR939,MIR1249,MIR1237,EIF4G1,AGO2,DND1,MIRLET7A3,MIRLET7B,MIR182,MIR183,MIR33A,MIR96,MIR339,MAP2K2,MIR769,NCOR2,MARF1", 
    "MIR877,MIR922,MIR939,MIR1249,MIR1237,EIF4G1,AGO2,DND1,MIRLET7A3,MIRLET7B,MIR182,MIR183,MIR33A,MIR96,MIR339,MAP2K2,MIR769,NCOR2", 
    "MIR877,MIR922,MIR939,MIR1249,MIR1237,EIF4G1,ZC3H7B,MORC1,AGO2,DND1,MIRLET7A3,MIRLET7B,MIR182,MIR183,MIR33A,MIR96,MIR339,DDX4,MAP2K2,MIR769,FAM172A,NCOR2,MARF1", 
    "AKAP8,TENT4A,NCAPD3,AKAP8L,GPER1,H1-6,CHMP1A,TTN,MCPH1", 
    "MIR877,MIR922,MIR939,MIR1249,MIR1237,TRAP1,TENT4A,ZC3H18,PNLDC1,DAPK3,DAZL,DXO,EIF4G1,AKT1,SAMD4A,LARP4B,CYFIP1,ZC3H7B,MTOR,MTG2,AGO2,ILF3,DND1,MEX3D,MIRLET7A3,MIRLET7B,MIR182,MIR183,MIR33A,MIR96,MIR339,HNRNPM,PRKDC,MAP2K2,DUS3L,EEFSEC,TRAF2,MIR769,NCK2,EIF3B,PER2,ZNF598,MTG1,TBRG4,NCOR2,MARF1", 
    "PDCD6,DNAJB6,CREBBP,DAXX,EP300,AKT1,MTOR,METRNL,HSF1,SLC27A1,MAPT,TRPV1,ZNF516", 
    "PDCD6,DNAJB6,CREBBP,DAXX,EHMT2,MTOR,HSF1,MAPT,TRPV1", "MIR877,MIR939,EIF4G1,AGO2,MIR182,MIR96", 
    "PDCD6,DNAJB6,CREBBP,DAXX,EP300,AKT1,MTOR,HSF1,MAPT,TRPV1"
    )), row.names = c("GO:0035194", "GO:0016441", "GO:0035195", 
"GO:0031047", "GO:0030261", "GO:0010608", "GO:0009266", "GO:0034605", 
"GO:0035278", "GO:0009408"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should give us a reproducible dataset for `dmrcate.granges.hyper`, otherwise we can't necessarily answer your question accurately. With that said, this might do the trick (I made up a fake GRanges object, `data_dummy`, to use in place of `dmrcate.granges.hyper`, but you should be able to apply this directly to your data):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plyranges)
data_dummy <- GRanges(Rle(rep('chr1', 3)), IRanges(c(1, 1001, 1001), width=c(rep(100, 2), 10000)), 
                      SYMBOL=c('NCOR2', 'ZNF516', 'ZNF516, EP300'))
data_dummy <- mutate(data_dummy, Pathway=map_chr(SYMBOL, function(x) {
  # if there are multiple SYMBOLs separated by commas (e.g. "X, Y, Z"), reformat as "X|Y|Z"
  x <- str_replace_all(x, ', ', '|')
  # pull out rows of gst.region.bp.hyper containing gene symbol(s) of interest in SigGenesInSet
  df <- gst.region.bp.hyper[str_which(gst.region.bp.hyper$SigGenesInSet, x),]
  # arrange in order of P.DE
  df <- arrange(df, P.DE)
  # return the TERM value from the first row (i.e. lowest P.DE, if there were multiple matches)
  return(df$TERM[1])
})) %>% print()
```

Output:

```
GRanges object with 3 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
      seqnames     ranges strand |        SYMBOL                Pathway
         <Rle>  <IRanges>  <Rle> |   <character>            <character>
  [1]     chr1      1-100      * |         NCOR2 post-transcriptional..
  [2]     chr1  1001-1100      * |        ZNF516 response to temperat..
  [3]     chr1 1001-11000      * | ZNF516, EP300 response to temperat..
```